# Torsion subsheaf of coherent sheaf on locally Noetherian scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian scheme and let $\mathscr{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$. I would like to construct the torsion subsheaf $T(\mathscr{F})$ of $\mathscr{F}$ in the following way: for any affine open $U \subseteq X$, denote $A = \Gamma \left(U, \mathscr{O}_X \right)$ and $M = \Gamma \left(U, \mathscr{F} \right)$. Define

$$ T(\mathscr{F})(U) = T(M) = \left\{ m \in M \,|\, \exists \,a \in A\text{ non-zero divisor such that } a \cdot m = 0 \right\}.$$

I want to prove that $T(\mathscr{F})$ is a coherent subsheaf of $\mathscr{F}$. To this end, I need to show two things:

(1) Torsion commutes with localisation: for any $f \in A$, $T(M)_f = T(M_f)$.

(2) Local sections glue uniquely: if $A$ is a Noetherian ring, $(f_1,...,f_r) = A$, $m \in M$ and for every $i \leq r$, $m \in M_{f_i}$ is torsion, then $m \in M$ is torsion.

For (2), it is proven [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/35328/122284). I tried to prove (1) myself. Firstly, there is an injective homomorphism

$$ T(M)_f \rightarrow T(M_f).$$

This follows from the fact that an element of $T(M)$ gets sent to an element of $T(M_f)$ under the localisation $M \rightarrow M_f$. I want to prove it is surjective. Let $(m, f^k) \in M_f$ be a torsion element, i.e. there exists a non-zero divisor $(a, f^j) \in A_f$ such that $(a m, f^{j+k}) \sim 0$. By definition of localisation, there exists an $l \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^l ( a m) = 0 \in A$. Note that $a$ is a non-zero divisor of $A$, hence $f^l m \in M$ is torsion. But then $(f^l m, f^{l + k}) \in T(M)_f$ and its image in $T(M_f)$ is $(m, f^k)$.

I would like to ask if this is correct. If it is, I am wondering why it is not written anywhere else. I know there is a similar (but non-equivalent) definition of pure sheaf which can be found in Huybrechts-Lehn. Why do people seem to prefer that one?

Comment: If $A$ is an integral domain and $M$ is any $A$-module you may define the torsion submodule $T(M)$ as the kernel of the canonical map $M \rightarrow M\otimes_A K(A)$ where $K(A)$ is the quotient field of $A$. If $X$ is integral there is for any $\mathcal{E}$ a canonical map $\phi: \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}\otimes K_X$ and you may ask if this globalize: If $T(\mathcal{E}):=ker(\phi)$,does this give a definition of the torsion subsheaf $T(\mathcal{E}) \subseteq \mathcal{E}$?

Comment: The sheaf $K_X$ is a sheaf of commutative $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras and you may form the tensor product $\mathcal{E}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} K_X$ and the map $\phi$ clearly exists. You may generalize $K_X$ to any scheme: The sheaf of total quotient rings $K^{t}_X$ of $X$ and there is a map $\phi^t: \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}\otimes K^t_X$. You may in complete generality define $T(\mathcal{E}):=ker(\phi^t)$ and ask if this sheaf has "nice properties".

Comment: If $X$ is integral and $U:=Spec(A)$ is an open affine subscheme, it follows $ker(\phi)_U \cong T(E) \subseteq E$ where $E:=\Gamma(U,\mathcal{E})$. Hence when $X$ is integral the above definition gives a definition of the torsion subsheaf.

Comment: If $X$ is integral, then torsion is well-defined. If you use the sheaf of total quotient rings, I am happy to believe that the torsion above defined is the kernel of $\mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E} \otimes K_X^t$ but you still need to prove that $K_X^t$ is quasi-coherent. This is not always true even if $X$ is Noetherian ([Lemma 0EMH](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EMH)).

Comment: Where at the stacks project homepage do you find an example where $K^t_X$ is not quasi coherent?

Comment: To my knowlege: The sheaf $K^t_X$ has the property that for any affine open subscheme $U:=Spec(A) \subseteq X$ it follows $K^t_X(U)\cong K^{tot}(A)$ where $K^{tot}(A)$ is the ring of total quotients of $A$. The ring $K^{tot}(A)$ is a quasi coherent $A$-module.

Comment: There is a counterexample in [Kleiman's paper](https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001%3A1979%3A25%3A%3A101). You can find it in the very last paragraph before the references (page 205 or page 4/5).

Comment: To me, the whole paper was unexpected.

Comment: In Hartshorne they define the sheaf $K^t_X$ and the notion "Cartier divisor" for any scheme $X$. The sheaf $K^t_X$ is not constructed explicitly however. In Liu's book the sheaf $K^t_X$ is constructed for any $X$ - do you know an error in Liu's construction?

Comment: @Ofiz Thanks for that paper, I didn't know this. Actually, some years ago I realized that the construction of $\mathcal K_X$ in my (rather old) version of Hartshorne does not simply work out, but the definition in a fellow student's (newer) version differed. This is a nice round up to that story.

Comment: @hn2020 I think Liu defines it in the same way as proposed by Kleiman, which I consider correct. This is also the same way Hartshorne defines it. Note that (in the notation of Liu) $\mathcal K'_X$ is only a *presheaf*, and one has to sheafify to obtain the sheaf $\mathcal K_X$. By definition $\mathcal K'_X(U) = K^{tot}(A)$ for open affines $U = \operatorname{Spec} A \subset X$, but this is not (in general) true for the *sheaf* $\mathcal K_X$.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "Let X be a locally Noetherian scheme and let F be a coherent sheaf on X. I would like to construct the torsion subsheaf T(F) of F in the following way: for any affine open $U⊆X$, denote $A=Γ(U,O_X)$ and $M=Γ(U,F)$. Define

$$T(F)(U)=T(M)=\{m∈M|∃a∈A \text{ non-zero divisor such that $a⋅m=0$} \}.$$

I want to prove that T(F) is a coherent subsheaf of F."

**Answer:** If $X$ is a locally noetherian integral scheme, there is a canonical map

$$\phi: E \rightarrow E\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} K_X$$

where $K_X$ is the "sheaf of quotient fields" of $X$. For any open subscheme $U:=Spec(A) \subseteq X$ it follows $K:=K_X(U)\cong K(A) \cong \mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$
where $\eta$ is the generic point. Let $\tilde{E}:=ker(\phi)$. It follows by an exercise in Atiyah-Macdonald that if $E(U) \cong M$ that $\tilde{E}(U)\cong T(M) \subseteq M$ is the torsion sub module of $M$. For the more general case you may try to use the sheaf of total quotient rings $K^{tot}_X$. This is claimed to exist in general in Liu's book on arithmetic algebraic geometry. From the discussion above and the reference: The sheaf $K^{tot}_X$ may not exist in complete generality. There is also a construction on the "stack project homepage" (Definition 31.23.1):

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01X1

Here they define the sheaf $K^{tot}_X$ for any "locally ringed topological space".

**Note:** Whenever you find a statement with a "proof" online and you need the statement in your research, you should check the proof: The net is unreliable.