# Restriction of torsion free rank $1$ sheaf on reducible curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $(S,H)$ be a polarized surface. Let $C_1, C_2\in |H|$ be two integral curves (not necessarily smooth) and $C\in|2H|$ be $C_1\cup C_2$. If $F$ is a  pure dimension $1$ sheaf supported $C$ with rank $1$, and consider the map by adjunction $r_1: F\to F|_{C_1}$.

Question 1: does $F|_{C_1}$ have to be torsion free?

Question 2: is $r_1$ surjective? (I realized the answer is obviously YES to this thanks to hm2020's answer/ also the right exactness of $\otimes$)

Thank you!

Comment: One definition of "torsion sheaf" is as follows: If $C$ is an irreducible curve and $E$ a QC sheaf, it follows $E$ is a torsion sheaf iff $E_{\eta}=0$ for $\eta \in C$ the generic point. Hence $E$ is "torsion free" iff $E_{\eta}\neq (0)$. In this case your curve is not irreducible hence there is no unique generic point $\eta$ - for this reason: include your definition ot "torsion free".

Comment: You find some discussion on this subject on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230232/torsion-subsheaf-of-coherent-sheaf-on-locally-noetherian-scheme/4235177#4235177

Comment: ..if this is your definition, and if $F_1:=F/IF$ one has to prove that $ker(\rho_1)=(0)$ when $\rho_1: F_1 \rightarrow F_1\otimes K^{tot}_{C_1}$ (assuming $ker(\rho: F \rightarrow F\otimes K^{tot}_C)=(0))$.

Comment: @hm2020 Thank you. I agree with your first comment. I should have used pure dim 1 instead of torsion free. I've edited the question above. I will have to think more about the third comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** Let $(S,H)$ be a polarized surface. Let $C_1, C_2\in |H|$ be two integral curves (not necessarily smooth) and $C\in|2H|$ be $C_1\cup C_2$. If $F$ is a torsion free rank $1$ sheaf on $C$, and consider the map by adjunction $r_1: F\to F|_{C_1}$.
Question 1: does $F|_{C_1}$ have to be torsion free? Question 2: is $r_1$ surjective?"

**Answer:** If $I⊆\mathcal{O}_C$ is the ideal sheaf defining $C_1⊆C$ as closed subscheme, it follows $F_{C_1}≅F/IF$ and $r_1$ is the canonical map $F→F/IF$, which is surjective. If the two curves are regular and the union is disjoint, a torsion free sheaf is locally free and its restriction to $C_1$ is again locally free.